# UITableviewCell text disappears after a blink on every reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Reload is not calling `cellForRowAt` whenever I am trying to reload without the main thread closure. This is my code:

```
class UtititySwitcher:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let utilityTableview = UITableView()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Mycell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
    return cell
}




func Open(loginID:String, view:UIView)
{
    let frm = view.bounds
    let backView = UIView(frame: frm)
    self.utilityTableview.frame = CGRect(x: frm.minX + 10, y: frm.midY - 50, width: frm.width - 20, height: 100)
    self.utilityTableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.utilityTableview.delegate = self
    self.utilityTableview.dataSource = self
    backView.addSubview(self.utilityTableview)
    view.addSubview(backView)

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.utilityTableview.reloadData()
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you adding reload function call inside operation queue? You should already be on the main thread. Are you calling open method from a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the delegate and data source for the `utilityTableview` so this table view is not informed who shall it listen to and take data from. At the class init, add 
`utilityTableview.delegate = self` 
and 
`utilityTableview.dataSource = self`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is :
     the OperationQueue have not init
you can try:

`let operationQueue = OperationQueue()`

`operationQueue.main.addOperation {`

```
    self.utilityTableview.reloadData
```

`}`